# Add row for each ID if ID doesn't have record at TIME point x

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a data set with concentration-time data that looks like this:

```
ID    TIME    TLD    DV   ANALYTE
1     0.00    0.00   NA   1
1     0.16    0.16   5    1
1     2       2      4    1
1     6       6      2.5  1
1     12      12     1    1
```

In reality, there are more IDs and more columns of course. Anyways, as you can see, ID 1 doesn't have a concentration (DV) record at for example TIME 4 and TIME 10. I want to write a code that adds a row when the TIME columns doesn't have a DV record for TIME 4 and 10 for every ID. The TLD record is the same value as TIME up until 168. After that, it resets to 0. DV should be NA for every added row. So I want to achieve something like this:

```
ID    TIME    TLD    DV    ANALYTE
1     0.00    0.00   NA    1
1     0.16    0.16   5     1
1     2       2      4     1
1     4       4      NA    1
1     6       6      2.5   1 
1     10      10     NA    1
1     12      12     1     1
```

I tried to do a for loop, but I'm not so familiar with it and it seems a bit complex to me right now. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Hi, if you found it helpful, I'd really appreciate it if you marked my answer as 'accepted', thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to create a separate dataframe (e.g. time_data) of the TIME values (and other similar vars like TLD) that you want first. Then you can `left_join()` your concentration data to time_data and it will have your desired effect. Like:

```
library(tidyverse)

conc_data <- tibble(ID = rep(1, 5),
                    TIME = c(0, 0.16, 2, 6, 12),
                    TLD = c(0, 0.16, 2, 6, 12),
                    DV = c(NA, 5, 4 ,2.5,1),
                    ANALYTE = rep(1,5))

time_data <- tibble(TIME = c(0,0.16,2,4,6,10,12),
                    TLD = c(0,0.16,2,4,6,10,12),
                    ID = rep(1,7))

left_join(time_data, conc_data)

Joining with `by = join_by(TIME, TLD, ID)`
# A tibble: 7 × 5
   TIME   TLD    ID    DV ANALYTE
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1  0     0        1  NA         1
2  0.16  0.16     1   5         1
3  2     2        1   4         1
4  4     4        1  NA        NA
5  6     6        1   2.5       1
6 10    10        1  NA        NA
7 12    12        1   1         1
```

For future reference, it makes it much easier if you show the code used to create your example data so we don't have to make it ourselves. Some explanation of where you get your random TIME intervals would help to abstract the solution.